# Replace in Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables `Tbl_A` and `Tbl_B` and data is as follows

Tbl_A

```
Company_nm  Website

Airindia    www.airindia.coin/index.html  
Spicejet    www.spicjet.com  
indigo      indigo.com/
```

Tbl_B

```
Company    URL

Airindia   www.airindia.co.in/index  
Spicejet   www.spicjet.com/index.html  
indigo     www.indigo.com/
```

My query is to select all the names of the companies by joining on website/Url columns of two tables by replaceing/removing additional characters after domain name. Final output should be all the 3 companies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `substring` and `charindex` to get the first part of the url:

```
select *
from   tbl_a a
join   tbl_b b
on     case
       when charindex('/', a.website) > 0
       then substring(a.website, 0, charindex('/', a.website))
       else a.website
       end
       =
       case
       when charindex('/', b.url) > 0
       then substring(b.url, 0, charindex('/', b.url))
       else b.url
       end
```

Comment: Actually the challenge over here is, in my actual data set there need not be "/" for all the records some could just end up with ".com" so I am not getting the desired output when I am using the above query in joins as if the query matches if and only if result set has "/" in it's record.

Answer (score 1):

i think you must use a 'pattern matching' way for your select query.
have a look at [Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx)
and [Pattern Matching (Regex)](http://www.sqllion.com/2010/12/pattern-matching-regex-in-t-sql/)
for more Information.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Parick answer i made changes and i think to use inner join to join the two table will be better idea in order to join matching data between two tables and join them together.

```
select *
from   tbl_a a
inner join   tbl_b b
on     substring(a.website, 0, charindex('/', a.website)) = substring(b.url, 0, charindex('/', b.url))
```

Comment: That is exactly the same as mine. `join` == `inner join`.

Comment: yes but if in the given question if is having many rows then the result will not be same of using inner join instead of simply join. It will lead to duplicates results

Comment: `inner join` doesn't deduplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Create a third column where you store the website or URL with only the domain name making matching faster & easier.